# Show the same site from two different subdomains

Tags: redirect, web

I have a website that is a small, one page html/css/js site. I want the viewers to be able to view the same site whether they are coming from www.domain.com or just domain.com, without redirection. Is this possible?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you want to avoid a redirect? If you use both domain.com and www.domain.com your search engine ranking can be affected as most search engines will see the two sites as separate; ranking each independently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What web server software are you using? IIS?

Have two A records, "www.yoursite.com" and "yoursite.com" point to same IP, and set the bindings on the site in your server to take in both request.

Comment: +1 In Apache, you'll want to edit the `ServerAlias` to have www.example.com and example.com; is IIS under the Advanced settings for the website, you'll see the host headers; add both www. and . there.  As for DNS, I generally set www. as a CNAME to the A record example.com for sheer laziness if I have to change it.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason why you can't just redirect DNS? That is, set up two address records that point at the server and the client will get the same site.